# Can't animate locations property for CAGradientLayer when number of locations changes

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I created a `UICollectionView` where the top and bottom of the view have a gradient. When you scroll to the bottom of the view the gradient disappears. I want to animate this change.

In my `UICollectionView` class:

```
func setupTopAndBottomGradientMask() {
    let coverView = GradientView(frame: self.bounds)
    guard let coverLayer = coverView.layer as? CAGradientLayer else {
        return
    }
    coverLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, 
    UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    coverLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.07, 0.93, 1.0]
    self.mask = coverView
}

func setupTopGradientMask() {
    let coverView = GradientView(frame: self.bounds)
    guard let coverLayer = coverView.layer as? CAGradientLayer else {
        return
    }
    coverLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    coverLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.07]
    self.mask = coverView
}
```

In `scrollViewDidScroll` in my `UIViewController` I added code to animate the change from the `setupTopAndBottomGradientMask()` state to the `setupTopGradientMask()` state:

```
    let colorsAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
    colorsAnimation.fromValue = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, 
    UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    colorsAnimation.toValue = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]

    let locationsAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    locationsAnimation.fromValue = [0.0, 0.07, 0.93, 1.0]
    locationsAnimation.toValue = [0.0, 0.07]

    let removeBottomGradientAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    removeBottomGradientAnimationGroup.animations = [colorsAnimation, 
    locationsAnimation]
    removeBottomGradientAnimationGroup.duration = 2
    removeBottomGradientAnimationGroup.timingFunction = 
    CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

    let existingMaskLayer =  mainCollectionView.mask?.layer as? CAGradientLayer
    existingMaskLayer?.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    existingMaskLayer?.locations = [0.0, 0.07]
    mainCollectionView.mask?.layer.add(removeBottomGradientAnimationGroup, forKey: "removeBottomGradientAnimationGroup")
```

This code creates the correct final UI but it does not animate. [This is a screencast of UI where the gradient changes but does not animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRVIS.gif)

I confirmed that if the locations array is the same size for the `locationsAnimation.fromValue` and `locationsAnimation.toValue` then it does animate.

My question: How can I achieve the animation I want given that `CABasicAnimation` doesn't support animating between CAGradientLayers with a different number of locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't surprise me that this happens. There is a similar issue with animating the path in a `CAShapeLayer`. In that case the number and type of control points in the path must be the same at the start and the end or the animation results are undefined.

You need to figure out an equivalent animation that still has 4 colors in the array.

You animate from `[clear, black, black, clear]` to `[clear, black]` and from locations `[0.0, 0.07, 0.93, 1.0]` to `[0.0, 0.07]`.

Why not animate from  `[clear, black, black, clear]` to `[clear, black, black, black]` with the same starting and ending locations. That should give the same effect.